# Debug Spring Boot app: Source not found NativeMethodAccessorImpl.class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resources

So, I am building a REST API using Spring Boot App. I was able to debug it but suddenly I get this error when I try to debug the app as Spring boot app using Spring Tool Set:

[image]

I can run the application with any problem but can´t debug it:/.

Do you guys know how to solve this? Where can I find this sources and how can I add them to my project?

Comment: you are trying to step through a jdk class. Do you really need to do that? Wouldn't a breakpoint in the classes that you are developing work?

Comment: I dont have any breakpoint in any jdk class. Ofc I don´t need it:)

Comment: you are stepping into it. That is why eclipse is trying to find the source for the class.

Comment: Thanks @efekctive, I just removed all the break points just in case and fixed the problem:)